# How to create +/- Button and and a delete button in Javafx using Eclipse IDE

Tags: java

**Thanks for the little intrest showed by a few, I was able to fix it up myself.**

```
@FXML
public void PlusMinusbutton(ActionEvent event) {
    String value=((Button)event.getSource()).getText();
    if(value.contains("+/-") && !result.isEmpty()){
          result.setText(0, result.length() - 1);
            }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: "Not working" isnt a working problem description.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include code in your question. Also, feel free to read up on this [open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Comment: I have done that now

Comment: Did you try `value.contains("+/-")` but be carefull you could get a Problem with normal + and - because for the program it seems to be the same

Comment: Yeah it didn't work, can you help me with delete button too?

Comment: The button to delete 1 character Right?

Comment: Yeah, please if you can

Comment: Can you give more Code So I can specify the answer to your Code and I don't have to use General expressions. I Need the string where you store the text which got entered by the user

Comment: Okay lemme get it

Comment: You could also take a look at my answer firsts if you want

Comment: Take a look now, I have posted the code

Comment: Does the delete button work with my example Code?

Answer (score 0):

Delete Button:

```
String text=result.getText();
text.substring(0,text.length()-1);
result.setText(text);
```

I have seen you forgot the substring in your Code so I made it like you should in your code

Comment: Take a look now

Comment: If your tried to do it like in your Question at the `+/-` button you did it wrong and you should check my answer one more time